# How to transfer public and private PGP keys to another computer?

Tags: macosx, pgp

How do I transfer public and private PGP Keys to a Mac OS X Lion machine?

Comment: Can you clarify what PGP implementation you use on both machines?

Comment: I am using seahorse / GnuPG on Ubuntu and GPGTools on Mac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you are using GnuPG on Ubuntu...

First, you should export them:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys <keyid>  >key.gpg
gpg --export <keyid>  >>key.gpg
```

Then you should transfer this file to the Mac via a **secure** channel and import the keys on the recipient. You should be able to import the key via the graphical GPG Keychain, or through the command line (`gpg --import key.gpg`).

If you need to use a insecure channel to transfer the private key, such as email or other network based channels (where you don't have proper certificates ensuring that you are really communicating with the correct machine), you must use PGP (or some other method) to keep you private key secure:

- On your Mac, create a temporary key pair send the **public** part to your Ubuntu machine
- On your Ubuntu, check the fingerprint of the received key and encrypt 'key.gpg' with it, also signing it with you own key
- Send both the Ubuntu **public** key and the **encrypted** 'key.gpg.gpg' file to the Mac
- Again on your Mac, check the fingerprint of the received key and decrypt/verify the received 'key.gpg.gpg' file

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use for blindly transferring all of my GnuPG keys and keyring. Might not be a "best practice," but works well enough for me.

Using [Magic Wormhole](https://github.com/warner/magic-wormhole).

```
$ brew install magic-wormhole     # OSX
$ sudo apt install magic-wormhole # Linux

# Computer with keys:
$ wormhole send --ignore-unsendable-files $HOME/.gnupg

# Computer without keys:
$ cd $HOME
$ wormhole receive
```